# Calculate correct cursor position with pan and zoom

Tags: c#, zooming, mouse, coordinates, pan

I've been messing around with this problem for about an hour now.

I have a viewport which supports panning and zooming, the panning is handled by storing an offset for the X and Y axis. The zoom is just a float going from 0.2 to 14.

My problem is that I need to be able to place stuff where the user clicks in the viewport but when I zoom and pan the mouse coordinates are not correct. I haven't been able to figure out how to properly calculate the mouse coordinates.

Here's an image showing what I have so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hKHH.png

As you can see the mouse origin is always at the top-left of the viewport component. You can see the pan X and Y offset as well as the zoom value in the bottom-left corner of the image. I've also added an example of the mouse coordinates in relation to the top-left of the viewport.

Now since in that image it's currently zoomed in the objects I place will be offset.

Thank you for your time!

**EDITED WITH SOLUTION THAT WORKS FOR MY CASE:**

```
void Viewport_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    Point mousePosition = new Point((int)((e.X - Pan.X) / Zoom),
                                    (int)((e.Y - Pan.Y) / Zoom));
}
```

This calculates a correct "screen-space" mouse position whilst taking the pan and zoom into account.
I got that solution by playing around with TaWs answer. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Which platform are you using? WPF, Winform..?? What control(s) are you using and how is the zoom implemented?

Comment: It's a winform and my control derives from the "UserControl" class. The zoom is just a float which is passed to the "ScaleTransform" method in the "OnPaint" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a TrackBar for the Zoom and two more for the offsets this seems to work:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename))
    {
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, trb_offsetX.Value, trb_offsetY.Value);
    }
}

float zoom = 1f;

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

  Point mouseLocation = e.Location;
  Point imageLocation = new Point((int)((mouseLocation.X / zoom - trb_offsetX.Value)),
                                  (int)((mouseLocation.Y / zoom - trb_offsetY.Value)));

   st_mousePos.Text = "   "  +  imageLocation.ToString();

}


private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    zoom = trackBar1.Value;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

I have added the code for the Paint event, so you can see if that's the way your are handling it, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I calculate the mouse position like that while I'm zoomed in I get a negative offset for the objects I place in my viewport. The way I handle my Paint method is I use "TranslateTransform(pan.X, pan.Y)" and I use "ScaleTransform(Zoom, Zoom)" after that.

Comment: I just figured it out by playing around with your example. What I did was I subtracted the pan offset from the mouse position and then divided the result of that by the zoom like so: "(int)((e.X - Pan.X) / Zoom)" and "(int)((e.Y - Pan.Y) / Zoom)". Thank you for your assistance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put you picture in to PictureBox and then calculate the relative position of the mouse. That is

```
    double Pic_width = orginal_image_width/ pictureBox.width;
    double Pic_height = orginal_image_height/ pictureBox.height;
    var mouseArgs = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    int xpoint = Convert.ToInt16(mouseArgs.X * Pic_width);
    int ypoint = Convert.ToUInt16(mouseArgs.Y * Pic_height);
```

this code will give you the position of the cursor in the image.