# How to find the coordinates of the mouse in the background image winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

I have a BufferedGraphics painted in the panel. The image is zoomed in and zoomed out. From this buffered graphic images how can i find the mouse position in the image not in the     panel.

```
  private void panel2_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
       {
         if (bitmap != null)
            {
                float widthZoomed = panel2.Width / Zoom;
                float heigthZoomed = panel2.Height / Zoom;

                if (widthZoomed > 30000.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = panel2.Width / 30000.0f;
                    widthZoomed = 30000.0f;
                }
                if (heigthZoomed > 30000.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = panel2.Height / 30000.0f;
                    heigthZoomed = 30000.0f;
                }


                if (widthZoomed < 2.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = panel2.Width / 2.0f;
                    widthZoomed = 2.0f;
                }
                if (heigthZoomed < 2.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = panel2.Height / 2.0f;
                    heigthZoomed = 2.0f;
                }

                float wz2 = widthZoomed / 2.0f;
                float hz2 = heigthZoomed / 2.0f;
                Rectangle drawRect = new Rectangle(
                    (int)(viewPortCenter.X - wz2),
                    (int)(viewPortCenter.Y - hz2),
                    (int)(widthZoomed),
                    (int)(heigthZoomed));
                drawrecX = drawRect.X;
                drawrecY = drawRect.Y;
                dispwidth = (int)(widthZoomed);
                dispheight = (int)(heigthZoomed);

                myBuffer.Graphics.Clear(Color.White); //Clear the Back buffer
                Console.WriteLine(this.panel2.DisplayRectangle.Width);
                Console.WriteLine(this.panel2.DisplayRectangle.Height);

                myBuffer.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, this.panel2.DisplayRectangle, drawRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                //pictureBox1.Image =
                myBuffer.Render(this.panel2.CreateGraphics());
                //this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Zoom: " + ((int)(this.Zoom * 100)).ToString() + "%";
            }  
}
```

the above code is the paint part.
To find the location of the mouse in the image i tried like this

```
private void panel2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var mouseArgs = (MouseEventArgs)e;
            double Pic_width = dispwidth / panel2.Width;//to find the relative position 
            double Pic_height = dispheight / panel2.Height;
            int xpoint = (int)Pic_width * mouseArgs.X + drawrecX;//drawrecX is the X coordinate from the drawing image
            int ypoint = (int)Pic_height * mouseArgs.Y + drawrecY;

        }
```

but this code does not give me the exact position.  any idea?

Comment: You'll have to apply the same transformation to the mouse position.  That's invariably *much* easier to do with the Matrix class.  You can directly assign it to the Graphics.Transform property to make it effective for painting.  And use it again to map the mouse position, use its TransformPoints() method.  Going back from image coordinates to mouse position, if necessary, gets easy as well, use the Matrix.Invert() method.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your feedback. But i don't know how to do it. Would you please give me a sample code or link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void panel2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    var mouseArgs = (MouseEventArgs)e;

    int x = mouseArgs.X - drawrecX;
    int y = mouseArgs.Y - drawrecY;

    var size = ImageSizeWithoutZoom;
    var zoomSize = ImageSizeWithZoom;

    double xPoint = x * size.X / zoomSize.X;
    double yPoint = y * size.Y / zoomSize.Y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it doesn't work. My image size and panel size is different, that is why i used the ratio of image with panel size. The image is zoomed in and out with panel2_MouseWheel event and then painted in the panel offset. Any other idea?

Comment: @Ebro It seems that you just need to multiply this values by zoom.

Comment: The mouseArgs X and Y coordinate is based on panel width and height. In my case the image is out of the panel size. This is the main problem to find the exact location.

Comment: _The image is zoomed in and out with panel2_MouseWheel event and then painted in the panel offset_ what is the 'panel offset'? you will have to explain..

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749318/calculate-correct-cursor-position-with-pan-and-zoom/24761580#24761580) is of interest?

Comment: @Taw my zooming is like any image viewer application. It zoomed outside of the window but you can move the pictures using mouse move event. It draws the picture as a background.