# How to position Panel scrollbars at specific position in C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a problem where I want to set and show the X/Y scrollbar positions in a Panel that contains an image.

I have this code for now, where I have defined `panel1` with `AutoScroll` set to `True`. I then load a picture in to the panel and resize the panel scrollers to fit the image size:

```
image = Image.FromFile("Image.jpg");
destinationRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(image.Width, image.Height);
```

I think that I better can explain my problem with pictures.

Let us say that I have this image here - it is 500x300 pixels:

[image]

I then also have my `panel1` defined - it is 190x170 pixels (smaller than the image). For better understanding the please replace "Display size" with "Panel size" in your mind:

[image]

So what I now want, is to place the visible area starting from image point X:90, Y:90 - this should of course then be reflected in the scollbars X/Y positions. Something like this (I of course only can see the red `panel1` content and not the full image):

[image]

I really cannot get my head around how to do this.

I thought that e.g. `AutoScrollPosition` or the `Paint` event for `panel1` could do the trick but that didn't work. Also I tried nesting panels, but no luck so there must be something I don't fully understand in this.

Would there be any ideas how to get my below pseudo code working (added the last line of code):

```
image = Image.FromFile("Image.jpg");
destinationRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(image.Width, image.Height);
panel1.AutoScrollXYPosition(90,90);
```

Any hints for how to set the horizontal and vertical scrollbar positions would really be appreciated :-)

The end goal will be a panel that will get zoomed in/out and where it can have multiple semi-transparent overlay panels on top - this is why I cannot use the `PictureBox` component.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749318/calculate-correct-cursor-position-with-pan-and-zoom/24761580#24761580 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57356394/14171304 ...

Comment: @dr.null - I am not sure how these are relevant compared to my problem? They might be useful for my upcoming zoom-stuff but I don't see a help in the vertical/horizontal scrollbar problems I have?

Comment: Yes, not direct answers since what you are asking here doesn't make sense at least to me. The two examples - and the similar ones in this context - are just a guess about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself ;-)

Adding an event handler for when the form has been shown and THEN afterwards set the `AutoScrollPosition` works for me.

If this could be done in a better way, then please let me know but for now my code looks something like this:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        image = Image.FromFile("Image.jpg");
        destinationRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(image.Width, image.Height);
        this.Shown += new EventHandler(this.Main_Shown);
    }

    private void Main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(90, 90);
    }
}
```